# sigma-algebra generated by two-sigma algebras is generated by the intersection of sets from these two sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ be two $\sigma$-algebras on a set $\Omega$.

Does it hold that $$\sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G}) = \sigma\{G\cap H: G\in\mathcal{G}, H\in \mathcal{H}\}?$$

How to prove it or disapprove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ be two $\sigma$-algebras on a set $\Omega$.
Let $S=\{G\cap H: G\in\mathcal{G}, H\in \mathcal{H}\}$.

Since $\Omega \in \mathcal{G}$, we have  that, for all $H\in \mathcal{H}$, $H = \Omega \cap H \in S$. So $\mathcal{H} \subseteq S$. In a similar way,
since $\Omega \in \mathcal{H}$, we have that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq S$.

So we have $\mathcal{G} \cup \mathcal{H} \subseteq S$. Then we have

$$ \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G}) = \sigma(\mathcal{H} \cup \mathcal{G}) \subseteq \sigma(S)\tag{1} $$

On the other hand, we have that $S \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})$, so we have:

$$ \sigma(S) \subseteq  \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G}) \tag{2} $$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have

$$\sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G}) = \sigma(S) $$

that is
$$\sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G}) = \sigma\{G\cap H: G\in\mathcal{G}, H\in \mathcal{H}\}$$